# DataGridView cell BackColor not formatting correctly

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, formatting

I have a datagridview in my app which lists active jobs.
One of the columns has a status code (0-5) and the rows are coloured depending on this value, like so...

```
     joblist.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine
     joblist.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black
```

if the status code is 0 then no colour is applied.

This bit works fine mostly, but I found that if it gets to several jobs with status 0, these jobs take on the colour of the last job which has a status of 1-5.

I can work around this by adding...

```
     elseif status=0 then
     joblist.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine
     joblist.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black
     end if
```

However, that wipes out my alternative rows colour, so if theres a block of white ones, they become hard to read.

Is there a way I can say something like...

```
  if status=0 then
  joblist.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = DefaultCellStyle.BackColor
  joblist.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = DefaultCellStyle.BackColor
```

... or whatever, to basically return the row in question to the default or alternative default style?

Comment: To better help us reproduce the problem you're seeing, please show the logic that is actually altering the colors for all status codes - including the method where the logic exists.

Answer (score 1):

Your snippets don't give a lot of context.  For instance, we have no idea which event you are using and there are several good candidates.  If the DGV is read only or the cell value cannot be changed, `RowPrePaint` is a good one to use since the row color will be set once only.  If it can change, then `CellFormatting` makes more sense to me.

Either way, to set them back, do a simple calculation and use the `DefaultCellStyle` colors.  This sets the row back color `MistyRose` for a status of 3, or back to the defaults for that row if it changes to something else:

```
If e.ColumnIndex = 2 Then
    If DirectCast(e.Value, Int32) = 3 Then
        dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.MistyRose
    Else
        Dim clr = If(e.RowIndex Mod 2 = 0, dgv1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor,
                     dgv1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor)
        dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = clr
    End If
End If
```

Initial Result (the yellowish `Consilk` color is the Alternating row back color):

[image]

Then, if I change the status for the second rosy row, it correctly uses the `AlternatingBackColor`:

[image]